# Simpler way to use an if function in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, appearance

I'm writing an if function that is just

IF(x<>0,x,y)

The problem is that x is an index match, which makes the formula long and a little hard to read. Is there a way to do this without having to repeat x? What I'm doing works fine, I would just like to make things a little more readable. I could do the index match in a different cell. Then x = cell, but I don't want to dirty up the workbook either.

Comment: [Lambda](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67) functions might work for you.

Comment: or [`LET()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999)....or, show us the actual formula with simplified data and maybe there is a way to do it even less complicated.

Comment: Regardless of your Excel version, you could define a name (in Name Manager) for x, and then you could use that 'variable' in lieu of x